# Combining Two Row Values as a dictionary item

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from dataframe. 1 row will be 'key' to dictionary item and 2 rows will be values of the same item.

Until now, I have

```
df : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>


d = {}
for i in df['KeyCol'].unique():
    d[i] = [{df['Col3'][j]: df['Col4'][j]} for j in df[df['KeyCol']==i].index]
print(d)
print(type(d))
```

But program gives error and says

```
line 1492, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What should I do?

Comment: `d[i]={df.loc[j,'Col3']: df.loc[j,'Col4'] for j in df[df['KeyCol']==i].index}`

Comment: thank you for your comment but I have the same problem.

Comment: maybe try exploring to_dict method of a dataframe for easy of use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand where I have mistake. 'KeyCol' has to have same value. I was trying to run program for different values. For this reason I had error.